# how 'text area' input control insert /r/n in text

Tags: asp-classic

I have text in database that don,t have '/r/n'. but when assign this text i  text area input control, it make next line(beak) in text area.

please let me know what 'return carries' it find in text and add '/r/n' in text.

first time '/r/n' not in text, before put in text area, but after put this in 'text area' n save , it save text with '/r/n'.

Comment: `Replace(text, vbCrLf, "")` should remove any carriage return line feed combination that you won't see in the database. You can also use `vbCr` and `vbLf` independantly if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm writing a text/string to the database, I run it through my clean() function. When I am pulling text/strings back out of the database to display, I run them through dirty(). I save both of these as include files as "i_fn_clean.asp" and "i_fun_dirty.asp". Here they are:

```
function clean(FixWhat)
    if (isempty(FixWhat) or isnull(FixWhat) or FixWhat="") then
        FixWhat=""
    else
        apos=chr(39)
        quot=chr(34)

        FixWhat=trim(FixWhat)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"''",apos & apos,1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"'''",apos,1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,VBNullChar,"",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,VBNullString,"",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,VBTab," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,VBVerticalTab," ",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&lt;","<",1,-1,1)      
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&gt;",">",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"/","&#47;",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"’",apos,1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"’",apos,1,-1,1)        
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"`",apos,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(145),apos,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(146),apos,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(180),apos,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(184),apos,1,-1,1)

        'quotes     
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(132),quot,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(147),quot,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(148),quot,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(152),quot,1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(168),quot,1,-1,1)

        'hyphens
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(150),"-",1,-1,1)
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(151),"--",1,-1,1)

        'dot dot dot
        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(133),"...",1,-1,1)


        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,vbCrLf & vbCrLf,vbCrLf,1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"[quote]","&#34;",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,quot,"&#34;",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"'","&#39;",1,-1,1)
    end if
    clean=FixWhat
End Function

Function dirty(FixWhat)
    if (isnull(FixWhat) or FixWhat="") then
        FixWhat=""
    else
        FixWhat=trim(FixWhat)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"  "," ",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#146;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&apos;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"%27","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#39;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#146;","'",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#47;","/",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"''''","'''",1,-1,1)


        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&#34;",chr(34),1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"%22",chr(34),1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,chr(13) & chr(10),"",1,-1,1)

        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&&","&",1,-1,1)
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&lt;","<",1,-1,1)      
        FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&gt;",">",1,-1,1)

        'FixWhat=replace(FixWhat,"&amp;","&",1,-1,1)

    end if
    dirty=FixWhat
End Function
```